# Localization in iOS app not working

Tags: objective-c, nslocalizedstring

When I launch my app in simulator localization works fine, e.g.

```
NSLocalizedString(@"HEAD", @"head")
```

In the simulator it gives me the correct text that I have defined in my Localizable.strings file.

But on device it prints just **HEAD** instead of the text.

Where is the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Is the language set on your iPhone exactly the same one set on the simulator?

Comment: No matter what I set the language on simulator, english or german, it works, but not on iPhone that is german

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default name for a localized strings file a device is looking for is Localizable.strings, rename your strings file, clean, and run.